# Best way to find element inside Parents JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that when the user types the city's post code, the name of the city is set to the city name input field. The search works fine but I can't get the relative id to the input field and set the name there. I can't hard code its ID because these forms are dynamically generated.

## file.JS

```
$("[id*=post_code]").on("input", function() {
    var el = $(this);

    if (el.val().length > 2) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: "post-code=" + el.val(),
            success: function(result, success, e) {
                        //DOES NOT WORK
                        $(e.target).parents(".city-auto").find("[id*=city]").val(result.name);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

## HTML

```
<div class="row 50% city-auto">
    <div class="3u 12u(narrower)">
        <div class="form-warning">
            {% if client_form.post_code.errors %}
            <spam><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}icons/warning_triangle_16.png" class="icon"> <spam class="icon fa-angle-down"></spam></spam>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <!-- Triggers JavaScript -->
        <input id="id_form-0-post_code" maxlength="5" name="form-0-post_code" placeholder="Post nr." type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
        <div class="form-warning">
        </div>
        <!-- Should get value replaced by JavaScript -->
        <input id="id_form-0-city" maxlength="30" name="form-0-city" placeholder="By" type="text" readonly="">
    </div>
</div>
```

This form is dynamically generated, so I need to be able to find the city input id by specifying a regular expression or using wildcard, like I did.

Comment: The IDs will change, so `id_form-0-city` will become `id_form-1-city` in another generated div. I must be able to identify from which parent should change it child's input value. In this case t should always be the parent of the field calling the function.

Comment: Is requirement to set `id="id_form-0-city"` value to value of `id_form-0-post_code` ?

Comment: @guest271314 No, I want to change the value of the field, not the attribute id.

Comment: try this  `$(e.target).parent(".city-auto").find("[id$=city]").val(result.name);` because it ends with city

Comment: Yes, see post . Can select `.parent().next()` then `.find("[id*=city]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
el.parent().next().find("[id*=city]").val(result.name);
```

Explanation

`el.parent()`:

```
<div class="3u 12u(narrower)">
```

`.next()`:

```
<div class="6u 12u(narrower)">
```

`.find("[id*=city]")`:

```
<input id="id_form-0-city" maxlength="30" name="form-0-city" placeholder="By" type="text" readonly="">
```

Comment: Yeps. It worked. What does next() do? It advances one level down?

Comment: _"What does next() do? It advances one level down?"_  Yes, as to `el.parent()`. See http://api.jquery.com/next .

Comment: Ohhhh ok. I see now. Thanks for the explanation. Why parent().children("class").find("id") wouldn't work?

Comment: _"Why parent().children("class").find("id") wouldn't work?"_ `.parent().children()` would reference same parent element , not next element of parent

Comment: I see. What about parents("city-auto").children("class").find("id")? I thought they could find the parents("limit") and then from that get the specified children("class") and look for something inside of it find("something").

Comment: _"What about parents("city-auto").children("class").find("id")?"_ Not necessary ? , though should return similar results ?

Comment: I tried that as well but didn't work. Anyways, I will read more the API and get to know more about that. Thanks for the help.